# Xcode bad coloring with shell script?

Tags: xcode, shell

It seems that Xcode really sucks at coloring the shell script. For example, if you copy the following snippet into your Xcode, most of the whole chunk is colored red.

```
### Creation of the GM template by averaging all (or following the template_list for) the GM_nl_0 and GM_xflipped_nl_0 images
cat <<stage_tpl3 > fslvbm2c
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f ../template_list ] ; then
    template_list=\`cat ../template_list\`
    template_list=\`\$FSLDIR/bin/remove_ext \$template_list\`
else
    template_list=\`echo *_struc.* | sed 's/_struc\./\./g'\`
    template_list=\`\$FSLDIR/bin/remove_ext \$template_list | sort -u\`
    echo "WARNING - study-specific template will be created from ALL input data - may not be group-size matched!!!"
fi
for g in \$template_list ; do
    mergelist="\$mergelist \${g}_struc_GM_to_T"
done
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslmerge -t template_4D_GM \$mergelist
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_4D_GM -Tmean template_GM
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslswapdim template_GM -x y z template_GM_flipped
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_GM -add template_GM_flipped -div 2 template_GM_init
stage_tpl3
chmod +x fslvbm2c
fslvbm2c_id=`fsl_sub -j $fslvbm2b_id -T 15 -N fslvbm2c ./fslvbm2c`
echo Creating first-pass template: ID=$fslvbm2c_id

### Estimation of the registration parameters of GM to grey matter standard template
/bin/rm -f fslvbm2d
T=template_GM_init
for g in `$FSLDIR/bin/imglob *_struc.*` ; do
  echo "${FSLDIR}/bin/fsl_reg ${g}_GM $T ${g}_GM_to_T_init $REG -fnirt \"--config=GM_2_MNI152GM_2mm.cnf\"" >> fslvbm2d
done
chmod a+x fslvbm2d
fslvbm2d_id=`$FSLDIR/bin/fsl_sub -j $fslvbm2c_id -T $HOWLONG -N fslvbm2d -t ./fslvbm2d`
echo Running registration to first-pass template: ID=$fslvbm2d_id

### Creation of the GM template by averaging all (or following the template_list for) the GM_nl_0 and GM_xflipped_nl_0 images
cat <<stage_tpl4 > fslvbm2e
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f ../template_list ] ; then
    template_list=\`cat ../template_list\`
    template_list=\`\$FSLDIR/bin/remove_ext \$template_list\`
else
    template_list=\`echo *_struc.* | sed 's/_struc\./\./g'\`
    template_list=\`\$FSLDIR/bin/remove_ext \$template_list | sort -u\`
    echo "WARNING - study-specific template will be created from ALL input data - may not be group-size matched!!!"
fi
for g in \$template_list ; do
    mergelist="\$mergelist \${g}_struc_GM_to_T_init"
done
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslmerge -t template_4D_GM \$mergelist
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_4D_GM -Tmean template_GM
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslswapdim template_GM -x y z template_GM_flipped
\$FSLDIR/bin/fslmaths template_GM -add template_GM_flipped -div 2 template_GM
stage_tpl4
chmod +x fslvbm2e
fslvbm2e_id=`fsl_sub -j $fslvbm2d_id -T 15 -N fslvbm2e ./fslvbm2e`
echo Creating second-pass template: ID=$fslvbm2e_id
```

It would look like this.

[image]

Is there a way whereby I can fix the Xcode coloring issue?

Comment: Xcode’s editor and syntax highlighting are pretty closely tied to Objectie-C and Swift. You may want to try another text editor for shell scripts and other languages, such as TextMate or Sublime Text.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Thanks a lot for the comment! Sublime is freaking awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's confusing Xcode's syntax highlighting here is specifically the combination of heredocs (`<<EOF`) and escaped backticks (`` \` ``).

There's no way to fix it as-is, but, so long as there is no substituted content in the heredocs, you can use a quoted heredoc to remove the requirement for escaped backticks in the first place:

```
cat <<'stage_tpl3' > fslvbm2c
...
template_list=`cat ../template_list`
...
stage_tpl3
```

When the terminating label for a heredoc is enclosed in quotes, substitutions within the heredoc are disabled. It works the exact same way, and Xcode is able to highlight it more gracefully. (As a bonus, it's also easier to read and write the script without all the backslashes in the way!)

---

As an aside, note that it's conventional to always use the label "EOF" for heredocs. Some editors special-case this for syntax highlighting. It's also easier to spot than something specific to the document.

Comment: also the `$( ... )` instead of the \` ... \` helps parsers sometimes.